# Position an element but want all following elements to position accordingly

Tags: html, css

Using CSS. I would like to position an element and have other elements position themselves accordingly on the page. Do I have to position each one individually, or is there a css command I can use to have positions follow each other?

At one point on my page I'd like elements to each overlap the one before it. So each one should move up a bit to overlap with the one over it. Is there a way I can have all the elements follow the first one, or do I need to do each manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CSS rule that tells all elements except for the first one in a group to have a negative margin top, this will make them overlap each other.

```css
.overlap {
  background: grey;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.overlap + .overlap {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlap"></div>
<div class="overlap"></div>
<div class="overlap"></div>
<div class="overlap"></div>
<div class="overlap"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! What you did makes sense. I'm a beginner, so my questions may be amateur, but if you can do this (what you showed above), why would anyone use position:relative; instead of just changing margins?

Comment: They have different applications. In your case, margins are the right tool to use. It's a rather broad question to answer, other than that sometimes position relative is the answer depending on what you're trying to accomplish. For instance, if you wanted to move one box to overlap without affecting the other boxes below it, you'd use position relative and top -40px.